# Open <url>http://... in object

Tags: qlikview

I have an expression in a Pivot table that creates a link and opens a pciture on the internet depending on the article number. It opens the picture in a new internet tab. 
Can I show the picture in an object or something else? We don't want a new tab to open.

```
=FieldName & '<url>http://www.......' & trim(ArticleNumber) & '.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes...use a text object and change the representation to an image. See here for steps:

https://community.qlik.com/message/771333#771333

Comment: Thank you! But in this solution you need to put all the url:s in the script. We have too many articles to do this.

Comment: If you can build the URL dynamically in an expression using the data that's loaded, then you should be fine. See this other example: https://community.qlik.com/message/749022#749022